# How to have a jQuery dialog stay inside a div

Tags: jquery-ui, dialog

I have tried to get a dialog (#dialog) stay inside a container div (#dialogContainer), i.e. I don't want it to be possible to drag the dialog outside the boundaries of the container div in the ui, but no success. I thought that the "appendTo" setting would fix this, but not. Any help is appreciated!

Here is an example that shows that it is indeed possible:
https://jqueryui.com/dialog

Code:

```
<div id="dialogContainer" style="width:600px;height:500px;border:1px solid blue;"></div>
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">
    This is dialog content.
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            position: {
                my: 'left top',
                at: 'left',
                of: $('#dialogContainer')
            },
            draggable: true,
            appendTo: "#dialogContainer",
            modal:true
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to restrict the dialog so it can't be dragged outside a container:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    ...
})
.parent().draggable({
    containment: '#dialogContainer'
});
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9sDMj/1/) for a Fiddle.